# How to put a MapsActivity inside another activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I created a "Google Maps Activity" (G) and "Navigation Drawer Activity" (N) from the wizard of Android Studio, when I use like Main Activity (Launch) the G activity, this show a mark (from the java source sample created on onMapReady method). But when a use the N activity like the main activity, and I copy the content from the "activity_maps.xml" inside "content_main.xml" to put the map inside the G activity, this don't show the mark. I guess the Java source for MapActivity of the G activity doesn't execute.

This is the directory tree:

[image]

This is the XML files:

[image]

And the Java code (I don't change nothing):

[image]

I tried to change in MapsAcivity "setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);" by "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);" thinking the activity_maps is copied inside content_main that is inside activity_main. Also, change in content_main "tools:context="com.example.ws02.myapplication.MapsActivity"" by "tools:context="com.example.ws02.myapplication.MainActivity"" because this work in the main_acivity.

Comment: You cannot put an activity in another activity. You are welcome to put a `MapFragment` or `SupportMapFragment` into another activity.

Comment: I think you should put your code as text instead of image.. just in case someone wants to copy and test your code.

Comment: I implemented OnMapReadyCallback interface, get the  NavigationView (findViewById(R.id.nav_view);) inside onCreate from MainActivity and copy onMapReady method inside MainActivity.java too, this work without problem. So at the final I don't use  "MapsActivity.java" file. But I want to separate the code for the map from everything else because this will be too large when I agree new methods. There is a way to do it?. i.e. if I can build the layouts with chunks, I can't do the same with the source code?, i.e. some Java source for every chunk of layout to join at the final?

Comment: Here is source (with the changes, but It does not convince me): https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ux9p1iv0jidx10x/AACrlxLfRZI_Ys157RuToSEPa?dl=0